# Using AND and OR clauses together in MS Excel IF function

Tags: excel, function, if-statement

I have a table as below:

```
Area  Owner/Tenant   Rent
----  ------------   -----
450        O         {IF..}
900        V
350        T
600        T
```

Conditions to be used:

```
1. If (Area <= 450) AND (owner/tenant = "O" OR "V"):
   True: 1330
   False: 1440
Formula: =IF(AND(D18<=450,OR(F18="O",F18="V")),1330,1450)
```

2. IF (Area > 450) AND (owner/tenant = "O" OR "V"):
   True: 1550
   False: 1660
   Formula: =IF(AND(D18>450,OR(F18="O",F18="V")),1550,1660)

I have been able to evaluate the two conditions above with individual IF formula. However, I am not able to combine the two formulae into a single formula that I would like to apply to the "Rent" column.

Can somebody please help?

BR, Piyush

Comment: Hi Piyush, Welcome to SO. Would you mind just clarifying the logic you're trying to use here. I have read it a couple of times and can't quite decipher what it is you want in the Rent column. Perhpas a brief explanation (with expected output) would help elucidate the problem for prospective respondants to your question

Comment: Sorry for that, Stewart. I would like to have the values mentioned against the true/false conditions against the 'Rent' column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making some assumptions here about what you want to happen, specifically what should happen based on which side of the `AND` statement causes it to evaluate to false, but I *think* I understand. I would use the following formula:

```
=IF(D18<=450,IF(OR(F18="O",F18="V"),1330,1450),IF(OR(F18="O",F18="V"),1550,1660))
```

This is embedding an additional conditional in your `THEN` and `ELSE` clauses.